# Running perl script on multiple files using Ant

Tags: perl, bash, ant

I have a set of files that I want to run a perl script on. The problem is they are not in the same directory. In fact they are all part of an ordered but complex directory hierarchy.

I wrote a Bash script that does what I want:

```
if [ ${HOME:+1} ]; then
    for A in ${HOME}/a/b/*; do
        for B in ${A}/c/*; do
            for C in ${B}/*; do
                if [ -f $C/somefile ]; then
                    some_perl_script $C/somefile;
                fi
            done;
        done;
    done;
fi
```

So that works, and it's not too complicated. However, I need that functionality to be available using Ant. Of course I could just call that script from Ant, but I want to know if there is anyway of having Ant do it in the first place, which seems like a more straightforward way of doings things. Essentially, I want something similar to the following build.xml:

```
<project name="application" basedir=".">
    <target name="apply_to_all">
      <exec executable="perl" dir="${basedir}">
        <arg value="some_perl_script.pl"/>
        <arg value="a/b/**/c/**/**/somefile"/>
      </exec>
    </target>
</project>
```

I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947437/ant-task-that-processes-multiple-files). However, I'd like to do it without ant-contrib.

Comment: you can simplify your bash loops: `for file in ${HOME}/a/b/*/c/*/*/somefile; do [[ -f "$file" ]] && some_perl_script "$file"; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the apply task to invoke your perlscript on all files that are included in the nested fileset(s) :

```
<apply executable="perl">
  <arg value="-your args.."/>
  <fileset dir="/some/dir">
    <patternset>
      <include name="**/*.pl"/>
    </patternset>
  </fileset>
  <fileset refid="other.files"/>
</apply>
```

Optionally use the attribute parallel = true, means run the command only once, appending all files as arguments. If false, command will be executed once for every file, default =false => see [Ant manual on apply](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html)
You may use [include / exclude patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html) and one or more filesets. F.e. you may use `**/*.pl` for
all your perl scripts.

Comment: That was simpler than I thought. Thank you!