# How to compress every file in a folder using Ant and Gzip

Tags: ant, gzip

Suppose I have a folder with many files. I want to have a .gz version of each file (not a tar.gz with all files). How do I do that with Ant? Ant's  doesn't accept a list of files, only operates on one. So how do I repeat this for all files, with a certain extension, in a directory?

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at a [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467991/ant-how-to-execute-a-command-for-each-file-in-directory).

Comment: Hmmm I knew about foreach... it is contrib anyway... I'd like to use a non contrib version.  With apply I could do but I need gzip executable. Other ways?

Comment: You could remove the need for the gzip executable with a rather convulated
    <apply "ant gzip.xml -Dfilename=" parallel="true"/>.  Of course you would need to define gzip.xml's default target as a <gzip> task.