# How to iterate a list of files and apply a command on each?

Tags: ant, command, iteration

I have a folder with two files (a.exe and b.exe) in it and I need to run a command on each. For example `xxx - a.exe a.bin`. Is there a way to do this with Ant?

I want ant to run:

```
xxx - a.exe a.bin
```

and

```
xxx - b.exe b.bin
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<apply>`.  Read more about it [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use `<foreach>` with a nested `<FileSet>`.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1467991/114029).