# How can I zip multiple folders individually with ant?

Tags: ant

If I have a folder with multiple subfolders (e.g. foo, bar, baz), how can I use ant to zip them individually into foo.zip, bar.zip and baz.zip, without doing them one by one?

Ideally there should also be a way to specify which files/subfolders to zip rather than "every single one".

Comment: What operating system are you using? This sounds like a job for the shell/command prompt.

Comment: Linux, and yeah it would be easy, but I specifically need it done with ant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use ant-contrib.  ant-contrib sucks, every time you use it, you're incurring technical debt.  The number one thing to keep in mind when using ant: let ant be ant.  ant is what it is. it's declarative.  [The original intent of ant](http://web.archive.org/web/20041217023752/http://x180.net/Journal/2004/03/31.html) was simple declarations of properties and with the meat of the work being done in java (where you had a real IDE with a debugger and test frameworks). As noted in [elements of ant style](http://wiki.apache.org/ant/TheElementsOfAntStyle) - "Let ant be ant".  If you have to use ant-contrib, you should make your own ant task.  If you can't do that, don't use ant.  ant-contrib takes the worst of ant ant makes it worse, you'll soon find things unmaintainable.  Enough ranting.

You don't even need to make a task for this one, this should work... it takes everything dir in /tmp and zips it up.  should get you most of the way there.

```
    <mapper id="zip" type="glob"
    from="*"
    to="*.zip"/>

<target name="zip-craziness">
    <apply executable="zip">
        <targetfile/>
        <srcfile/>
        <dirset dir="/tmp" />
         <mapper refid="zip"/>
    </apply>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there something like "apply" that runs ant tasks rather than external programs (without ant-contrib)?

Comment: yes and no, the doesn't support a mapper or redirector - you could make a zip task that did.   You're exactly right that it's sub-optimal to call out to the zip executable... it should nearly always work on your linux box, but you're going to have trouble on a pc.

Comment: "the doesn't support a mapper or redirector" - the what?

Comment: doh. that should have read: "the zip ant task doesn't support a mapper or redirector".  I shouldn't even try to type before coffee.

Answer (score 0):

I used  [for-each from ant contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) for this kind of thing. You may able to improve on this question : [Ant: How to execute a command for each file in directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467991/ant-how-to-execute-a-command-for-each-file-in-directory)