# Append text to multiple files in a directory using Ant

Tags: java, ant

I need to use ant to append some text to multiple files in a directory. I know I can use the echo command but how can I apply it to multiple files selected by a wildcard?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467991/ant-how-to-execute-a-command-for-each-file-in-directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by means of the Ant [`replaceregexp` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html).  For example this will append to all the `.txt` files in the specified directory:

```
<replaceregexp match="$" replace="your text here" flags="s">
    <fileset dir="my_dir" includes="*.txt" />
</replaceregexp>
```

The `flags` and `match` attrributes in this case configure the task to append only to the end of the file.

You man need to make use of the `${line.separator}` property in your append text if it is multiline.