# Ant - iterate on a folder to get run arguments

Tags: java, ant

I have an ant script that compile my program, build the jar and then run it. My program takes one argument that is a file.

In my run target I would like to be able to execute my jar with all the files that are in a specified folder, one by one, as argument.

Do I have to write all the different cases by hand like:

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
     <mkdir dir="${output.dir}" />
     <java jar="${myjar}.jar" output="${output.dir}/${test1}" fork="true">
          <arg value="${test.dir}/${test1}" />
     </java>
     <java jar="${myjar}.jar" output="${output.dir}/${test2}" fork="true">
          <arg value="${test.dir}/${test2}" />
     </java>

     #and so on

</target>
```

or is there a way to maybe *iterate* over my test directory and save me the writing of 20 other cases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution using the `<apply>` tag ([doc](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html)).

My script looks like it now and every execution is outputted in separate files thanks to the `<redirector>` tag:

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <mkdir dir="${output.dir}" />
    <apply executable="java">
         <fileset dir="${test.dir}" />
         <arg value="-jar"/>
         <arg path="${jar.dir}/${myjar}.jar" />
         <srcfile />
         <redirector>
              <outputmapper id="out" type="glob" from="*" to="${output.dir}/*" />
         </redirector>
    </apply>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreach tag in ant-contrib does what you want.  Give it a fileset and point it at the target that runs your jar.

Comment: yes I didn't want to have to install something else... I just found the answer I couldn't find before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467991/ant-how-to-execute-a-command-for-each-file-in-directory, that uses the `apply` tag. I'll try it.