# Trying to get the filenames of all files in a directory with ANT

Tags: ant

For example

```
/test/a.jar
/test/b.jar
/test/c.jar

output:
a.jar
b.jar
c.jar
```

This works for the most part, except it only seems to be getting one of the files, not all =/

```
       <for param="file">
            <path>
                <fileset dir="${test.dir}/lib">
                    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
            </path>
            <sequential>
                <basename property="filename" file="@{file}"/>
                <echo message="${filename}"/>
            </sequential>
        </for>
```

This just gets me:

```
c.jar
c.jar
c.jar
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem you've hit is the immutability of Ant properties - once a property is set the value cannot normally be changed.

The first time around the loop the `filename` property is being set, and that value 'sticks'.

Since Ant 1.8 the [`local` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html) allows you to localise a property to the current execution block.  For example, your `sequential` would be:

```
<sequential>
    <local name="filename" />
    <basename property="filename" file="@{file}"/>
    <echo message="${filename}"/>
</sequential>
```

Ant forgets the property at the end of the sequential, so a new value can be used in each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I've done anything with ant, but have you tried a foreach?

```
   <foreach>
        <fileset dir="${test.dir}/lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <echo message="${foreach.file}"/>
   </foreach>
```

Comment: foreach doesn't allow nested echo :(
I want to output the filenames to a file, so pretty much need to echo out to a file. I can't store them in a list because the number of files can change.

Comment: hmm.. check out this answer, maybe it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467991/ant-how-to-execute-a-command-for-each-file-in-directory

Comment: Yeah, I've been reading through, I just ended up doing an exec doing ls > out.txt :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I list files in a directory.

```
<fileset id="filesref" dir="path/to/dir" includes="*"/>
<property name="files" refid="filesref"/>

<echo message="Files:${line.separator}" />
<for list="${files}" delimiter=";" param="file" >
    <sequential>
        <echo message="    @{file}"/>
        <!--Do more stuff with the file's name here-->
    </sequential>
</for>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get list of file Names along with their sizes.

```cmd
E:\ANT>ant -buildfile=nashornFileNames.xml
Buildfile: E:\ANT\nashornFileNames.xml
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project name="MyProject" basedir="." default="fileNames">

    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="library.file" value="E:\\ANT\\JAR"/>


    <condition property="fileSep" value="\"><os family="windows"/></condition>
    <condition property="fileSep" value="/"><os family="unix"/></condition>

    <target name="fileNames" depends="showEnv">
        <!-- script run both on rhino and nashorn -->
        <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
            // "nashorn:" pseudo URL scheme for nashorn's built-in scripts.
            // To support Rhino load Mozilla compatibility script - which defines global functions like importPackage, importClass for rhino compatibility.
            load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");

            // Accessing Java packages and classes from script. Nashorn's recommended way to access Java classes is to use Java.type.
            importPackage(java.io) // Rhino extensions: importPackage global function
            importClass(java.lang.System); // Rhino extensions:  global.importClass

            var File = java.io.File; // Rhino way!
            var String = Java.type("java.lang.String"); // Nashorn way!

            // Access to Ant-Properties by their names
            basedir  = self.getProject().getProperty("basedir");
            fileSep  = project.getProperty("fileSep");
            System.out.println(" [script command-line] Java API : " + fileSep);

            // create and use a Task via Ant API
            echo = self.getProject().createTask("echo");
            function setMessage( msg ) {
                echo.setMessage( msg );
                echo.perform();
            }
            setMessage("[echo Task] Ant API : " + basedir );

                // <fileset dir="" includes=""/> « https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html
                var fileset = project.createDataType("fileset");

                files  = project.getProperty("library.file");
                setMessage("files: " + files);
                fileset.setDir( new File( files ) );
                fileset.setIncludes("**/*.jar");

            // Get the files (array) of that fileset
            ds = fileset.getDirectoryScanner( self.getProject() );

            fileset_files = ds.getIncludedFiles(); // Get only the files

            // iterate over that array
            for (i=0; i < fileset_files.length; i++) {

                var basedir  = fileset.getDir( self.getProject() );
                var filePath = fileset_files[i];
                var folders = filePath.split(fileSep).slice(0,-1).join(fileSep);
                var fileName = filePath.split(fileSep).slice(-1)[0];
                var file = new File(basedir, filePath);
                var fileSize = file.length();

                setMessage(folders + "« FileName : "+ fileName +" : " + fileSize + " byte");
            }
        ]]></script>
    </target>
    <target name="showEnv">
        <echo message="java.io.tmpdir = ${java.io.tmpdir}"/>
        <echo message="windows tmpdir = ${env.TMP}"/>
        <echo message="windows JAVA_HOME = ${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
        <echo message="windows ANT_HOME = ${env.ANT_HOME}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

[*Oracle Nashorn*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html) *as a command-line tool and as an embedded interpreter in Java applications*<sup>[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine))</sup>

Nashorn is a JavaScript<sup>ECMA-compliant</sup> engine developed in the Java programming language by Oracle. It is based on the [*Da Vinci Machine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_Vinci_Machine) (JSR 292) and has been released with Java 8. _
[`jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine`](https://www.javatips.net/api/openjdk-master/nashorn/src/jdk.scripting.nashorn/share/classes/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/NashornScriptEngine.java) <sup>[openjdk](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~sundar/8037400/webrev.01/src/jdk/nashorn/api/scripting/)</sup>

*Until Java SE 7, JDKs shipped with a JavaScript scripting engine based on Mozilla Rhino. Java SE 8 will instead ship with a new engine called Oracle Nashorn, which is based on JSR 292 and invokedynamic. It provides better compliance with the ECMA normalized JavaScript specification and better runtime performance through invokedynamic-bound call sites.*

[*Nashorn extensions*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions) and some of [*Rhino*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Rhino+Migration+Guide) specific extension which are already supported by nashorn.
Ex:

```java
var String = Java.type("java.lang.String"); // Nashorn way!
var Array = java.lang.reflect.Array // Rhino way!

// collections are interpreted as arrays.
var arr = [ "hello", "world" ];
var list = Java.to(array, Java.type("java.util.List"))
```

There are few Rhino/Mozilla extensions that are supported only if you load the compatibility script provided by nashorn. The compatibility script is loaded using "load('[`nashorn:mozilla_compat.js`](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~sundar/8010924/webrev.00/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/resources/)")