# How to unzip all files from a directory without having their name at disposal

Tags: ant

I want to search my directory(let us call it src) for a pattern and copy all the jars to some particular location(let us call it dest).

From dest I need to take jar files one by one and unzip them and delete them after unzipping them.

I can copy jar files to destination but how will I unzip them since I don't know their name because I want to give only the pattern as an input rest all should be done by the program.

SO how do I unzip all files from a directory without having their name at disposal

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ant: How to execute a command for each file in directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467991/ant-how-to-execute-a-command-for-each-file-in-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Do you create a fileset to copy the JARs? If so, you can pass that same fileset into the [Unzip](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html) task.

```
<copy todir="dest_dir">
  <fileset dir="src_dir">
    <exclude name="**/*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>

<unzip dest="dest_dir">
  <fileset dir="dest_dir">
    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</unzip>
```