# Variable number of parameters using <macrodef> and exec

Tags: ant

I am using *exec* to invoke a command line program multiple times from an ant build.xml. This command line program takes variable number of arguments for different cases.

At the moment I am calling this external program multiple time using  exec and code looks cluttered. For example:

```
<exec dir="./deploy_abc/bin" executable="python" failonerror="true" >
    <arg line="tests.py"/>
    <arg line="-h aaa"/>
    <arg line="-u bbb"/>
    <arg line="-p ccc"/>
</exec>

<exec dir="./deploy_abc/bin" executable="python" failonerror="true" >
    <arg line="tests.py"/>
    <arg line="-h ddd"/>
    <arg line="-u eee"/>
    <arg line="-p fff"/>
    <arg value="this is second test"/>
</exec>

<exec dir="./deploy_abc/bin" executable="python" failonerror="true" >
    <arg line="tests.py"/>
    <arg line="-u bbb"/>
    <arg line="-p ccc"/>
    <arg value="this is another test"/>
</exec>
```

So I am planning to refactor this build.xml file using macrodef.

My question is how to pass variable number of parameters to macrodef. As it is shown above I need to pass different arguments to the exec-ed program based on the scenario.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a [`macrodef` `element`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) to support this:

> This is used to specify nested elements of the new task. The contents
>   of the nested elements of the task instance are placed in the
>   templated task at the tag name.

For example, you might define your macro like this:

```
<macrodef name="call-exec">
   <attribute name="dir"/>
   <attribute name="executable"/>
   <attribute name="failonerror"/>
   <element name="arg-elements"/>
   <sequential>
      <exec dir="@{dir}" executable="@{executable}"
                       failonerror="@{failonerrer}" >
         <arg-elements />
      </exec>
   </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

And call it like this:

```
<call-exec dir="./deploy_abc/bin" executable="python" failonerror="true" >
  <arg-elements>
    <arg line="tests.py"/>
    <arg line="-u bbb"/>
    <arg line="-p ccc"/>
    <arg value="this is another test"/>
  </arg-elements>
</call-exec>
```

Comment: Very helpful, particularly in combination with `if:true`/`unless:true` (described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18243290/6251951) answer) for scripts which need to be invoked differently by operating system.