# ant: delete files from dir 'a 'that exist in dir 'b'

Tags: ant

Given two directories ('a' and 'b'), each containing files, neither containing directories.

My goal is to remove all files from 'b' that for which there are files with the same name in 'a'.

Can anyone suggest an ant recipe for this (short of writing javascript or java code)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at how fileset [selectors](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) work in Ant, specifically the [present](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#presentselect) selector.

The following contains an example:

- [How do I iterate through files in an ant script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434001/how-do-i-iterate-through-files-in-an-ant-script/20436488#20436488)