# ANT Script to run the queries present in a set of files

Tags: ant, rdf, sparql

I have an ANT task which uses an RDF file - cpldm.ttl and run a query on it which is present in the file- ASK-ldm.rq. It is done using JAVA ant tasks. The code is given below-

```
<java classname="arq.sparql" fork="true" outputproperty="javaresult" errorproperty="javaerror1">
 <arg value="--data=${tools.dir}/build-config/SPARQL/cpldm.ttl"/>
 <arg value="--query=${tools.dir}/build-config/SPARQL/ASK-ldm.rq"/>
 <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024M"/>
 <classpath>
   <path> 
     <fileset dir="${jena.dir}/lib">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
     </fileset>
   </path>
 </classpath>
</java>
```

Now I want extend this by using a set of SPARQL query files (.rq) / fileset. Like 'ASK1-ldm.rq', ASK2-ldm.rq etc and for each of them I want to capture the 'outputproperty' after the query is run on the same RDF file 'cpldm.ttl'

I hope I had been able to explain the challenge proeprly, if not feel free to ask.

After using Simon's suggestion the final code is-

```
<target name="validation">
  <foreach target="javatask" param="queryFile">
    <fileset dir="${tools.dir}/build-config/SPARQL/Queries">
      <include name="*.rq"/>
    </fileset>
  </foreach>
</target>
<target name="javatask">
   <java classname="arq.sparql" fork="true" outputproperty="javaresult" errorproperty="javaerror1">
       <arg value="--data=${tools.dir}/build-config/SPARQL/cpldm.ttl"/>
       <arg value="--query=${queryFile}"/>
       <jvmarg value="-Xmx1024M"/>
       <classpath>
          <path>
              <fileset dir="${jena.dir}/lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
              </fileset>
         </path>
       </classpath>
   </java>
   <fail message="Error at: ${javaerror1}">
       <condition>
        <not>
         <equals arg1="${javaerror1}" arg2=""/>
        </not>
      </condition>
  </fail>
      <echo message="Result for {queryFile} is: ${javaresult}"/>
</target>
```

In the out put I am first getting this message-

```
[foreach] The nested fileset element is deprectated, use a nested path instead
```

Then in the out put it is showing-

```
javatask:
 [echo] Result for {queryFile} is: Ask => Yes
```

First, what does that error message mean, and I want to see the name of the 'queryFile' in the put put so that I know which file gave what result.

Any more help?

Comment: the depercation warning is about you using a <fileset> element, and the foreach task asking you to use a <path> element instead. This is because filesets do not have any order, and paths do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this without coding java you can achieve the result by wrapping this java task in a [macro](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html). That macro can then be called once per file that you want to process. If you don't want to call the macro multiple times by hand you can use the [foreach task from ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html).

If you are not against creating your own ant task for this I'd suggest you read ["Writing you own task"](https://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html). If you know java it is really not that hard to create Ant tasks. Your own task can be specified in such a way that it handles filesets and calls the original java class for each of them.

Update: [An example for foreach can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467991/ant-how-to-execute-a-command-for-each-file-in-directory). As you can see it actually can call a task multiple times, so you don't need to create a macro in that case.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but giving a message which I am not sure about. I am giving the whole code that I am using and the output I am getting.

Comment: You forgot a $ in front of {queryFile}.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was embarassing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Simon, I hope you can help me a bit more. Is there any any way I can store the 'output' all the time to a text file in a particular location?

Comment: use the http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html task with output attribute set to the file, and append="true"