# How to use ant unzip to include nested zip file?

Tags: ant, war, unzip, ear

I have an ear file which includes war files and jars.
I'm using the unzip task to unzip the ear.
the problem is that I want to see in my destination folder the war files etracted as well.
for eample:
I have c:\example.ear inside i have 1.jar, 2.jar 3.war, 4.war
after extractio I would like to see:

```
c:\exmple
  3.war (d)
  4.war (d)
  1.jar (f)
  2.jar (f)
```

when d=directory f=file

Comment: A war file is a zip file too. So unzip it, the same way you unzipped the ear.

Comment: I tired it, the different is that an ear is one file wich I can set src and dest. after extraction I can use unzip again with fileset, but then I'm getting all of the files  unziped in under the parent folder. I would like to keep the name of the war as the name of the nested directory.

Comment: You probably want to use the ant-contrib's foreach task. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467991/ant-how-to-execute-a-command-for-each-file-in-directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, apperantaly you cannot create a folder with the same name of a war file in the same location.
So what I did in the end was move the war file to a tmp folder and unzip from there to the previous location.
solve the trick :-)