# Using Ant date properties?

Tags: ant, build

I am using Ant to build a fileset. I only want to include files in the file set that have been modified after a specific date. (See below)

Ideally I would like the below datetime value to be some sort of property that is equal to the create date of the build file. E.g. I only want files included in the fileset that where modified after the build file was created I cant use a static string because this build file will be checked out from subversion by multiple developers.

```
<fileset dir="some-files">
    <date datetime="07/12/2010 12:00 AM" when="after"/>
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Date svn keyword](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) in one of your property files, so your property would look like:

```
file.mod.date=$LastChangedDate$
```

once you have set the svn:keywords property on your property file (see the `svn propset` command), commited your changes checking out the property file will result in your property looking something like:

```
file.mod.date=$LastChangedDate: 2006-07-22 21:42:37 -0700 (Sat, 22 Jul 2006) $
```

Now you have an ant property with a date inside of it, there are [a couple of ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945374) to substring the property so you can use the raw date.

Comment: I wonder if I could use this technique to add the date directly into the build file?

Comment: @tinny, there is nothing stopping you from doing that `<property name="file.mod.date" value="$LastChangedDate$">`.  Just make sure to add the appropriate `svn propset` on the file you want svn keyword replacement on.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I can't test this at the moment, but it seems like you could do something like:

```
<fileset dir="${some-dir}">
    <depend targetdir="${basedir}">
        <mergemapper to="${ant.file}"/>
    </depend>
</fileset>
```

Without testing, I'm not sure what the exact interaction is between `depend` and `mergemapper`, but hopefully you get the idea...

Comment: Just noticed that the original question stated: "...only want files included in the fileset that where modified after the build file was created..." The `depend` selector uses modification time, not creation time.