# Read a dynamic substring from text file using ant

Tags: ant

I want to read a text file which has text as follows(sample)
`abc ip-32-56-198-18.com xyz`
now the text `32-56-198-18` updates dynamically and now i want to take this text and create ip address for further use.

I have done this using PHP but with ant i am in problem as I cant get the position of specific sub-string like php in ant.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945374/how-to-pull-out-a-substring-in-ant) question its similar but he knows the position of the sub-string my position is too not fix as `abc` can be string of any length. Only `ip-` and `.com` are fix which are sufficient to find the required.

If you all say that its not possible using ant then i can focus or do something else or try different method to fix my problem dropping the plan of reading the same from ANT.

Thanks to all.

Update: `abc ip-23-56-89-45.com-asdhba.sip-65-59-85-12.com xyz`

for the above example the code should work and it should give me `23-56-89-45`
Thanks.

Comment: Can you try **indexOf()** in **substring()**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the most rated answer to the question you mentioned, you could try using [PropertyRegex](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) from [Ant-conrtib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/).

```
<project>

<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="./ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>

<!-- You can load the value from file -->
<property name="input" value="abc ip-32-56-198-18.com xyz"/>

<propertyregex property="ip"
              input="${input}"
              regexp=".*?ip-(.*?)\.com.*"
              select="\1"
              defaultValue="${path}" />

<echo message="IP addr: ${ip}"/>
</project>
```

Comment: :your code works but in my text .com comes again and your code is not stopping at first occurance of `.com` it goes further and stops at last occurance of `.com` Please help....

Comment: please don't say use twice the same code! This should be last option.

Comment: For the Updated problem i used `regexp=".*ip-(.*)\.com(.*)\.com"`
This is as we select `\1` that means we are using the first one and if i do `\2` it gives the second text. Thanks once again..

Comment: @IAH2iV I've updated the regexp in the sample to ungreedy match. Now it works with your both inputs.