# Convert a property to a path

Tags: ant

I have a property of comma seperated values, eg. a,b,c

I want to break this apart and create a path of different filesets; eg.

```
<path id="compile.path">
  <fileset dir="..\a\lib\"/>
  <fileset dir="..\b\lib\"/>
  <fileset dir="..\c\lib\"/>
</path>
```

Is this possible? How do I do it? I'm not very familiar with ant. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a custom script or a non-standard Ant task.  Have a look at [this SO answer which explains how to get a substring form a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945374/how-to-pull-out-a-substring-in-ant) to get you started.

Comment: I was hoping that this would not be the case. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Another way write a for loop, iterate the original property based on a seperator and call a target from the loop for each token.

```
    <foreach list="${property}" delimiter="${line.separator}" target="mytarget" 
param="token" />
```

Then the called target:

```
<target name="mytarget">
    <echo>${token}</echo>           
</target>
```

Comment: I need to create a path element. I'm familiar with the foreach but I cannot use it to build up a path element.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `PropertySelector` from ant-contrib

```
    <property name="package.ABC.name" value="abc pack name" />
    <property name="package.DEF.name" value="def pack name" />
    <property name="package.GHI.name" value="ghi pack name" />
    <property name="package.JKL.name" value="jkl pack name" />

    <propertyselector property="pack.list"
                         delimiter=","
                         match="package\.([^\.]*)\.name"
                         select="\1"
                         casesensitive="false" />               
would yield the results  
ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL
```

Comment: This didn't satisfy my requirements as it uses one or more properties to create another property. I need a path element.