# Calling replace on string throws EvaluatorException

Tags: java, javascript, regex, ant, rhino

I'm trying to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938189/1468366) to the case of regexp replacement:

```xml
  <scriptdef name="propertyregex" language="javascript">
     <attribute name="property"/>
     <attribute name="input"/>
     <attribute name="regexp"/>
     <attribute name="replace"/>
     <![CDATA[
       var input = attributes.get("input");
       var regex = new RegExp(attributes.get("regexp"));
       var replace = attributes.get("replace");
       var res = input.replace(regex, replace);
       project.setProperty(attributes.get("property"), res);
     ]]>
  </scriptdef>
```

However, executing that code I always get an exception:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException:
The choice of Java constructor replace matching JavaScript argument types
(function,java.lang.String) is ambiguous; candidate constructors are: 
    class java.lang.String replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)
    class java.lang.String replace(char,char)
```

How can I do regular expression replacement here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem appears to be that this variable `input` is of the *Java* type `java.lang.String`, which apparently is not the native String type of Rhino. You can avoid this problem by explicitely constructing a JavaScript string:

```js
       var input = new String(attributes.get("input"));
```

Comment: Yes, if you evaluated `typeof(attributes.get("input"))` you would get `"object"`. More simply, `String(attributes.get("input"));` would also work. Note that in Nashorn, the JDK 8 JavaScript implementation, native `java.lang.String` are treated as strings on the JavaScript side.

Comment: This was my problem as well. My JS script under Solr worked on Windows and not under linux. I referred to your answer and it works on both now. As per @DavidP.Caldwell's comment, I changed the JDK on Linux from OpenJDK to Oracle JDK and it works that way as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I have found another answer on [Alfresco forum](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/other-apis/ambiguous-call-stringreplace-javalangstrings-02152012-0536).

The problem is, that when the JS code is interpreted, the type of `input` can't be determined for sure. It could be `java.lang.String` or Javascripts's `string`. The proposal from the forum worked for me - just to "cast" `input` object to JS `string` like this:

```
 var res = (input + "").replace(regex, replace);
```

Note: I've just concatenated the input with empty string.

Hope this helps.